# Html Video playsinline loop is not seamless on IOS 16

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I have a website with video playing in the background in loop. The video is edited to have a seamless loop and it works perfectly fine on desktop. However, when I open the website on IOS the video has a small delay before another loop. Does anyone have a solution for this? Or is it just an IOS issue that is out of our control?

Repo for full understanding: https://github.com/meri-maki/stack-video

SCREEN VIDEO to see what i mean by delay/lag: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/JpX7jpqWx7Ywdw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/resetNew.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/globals.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/welcome.css" />
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="welcome-section" >
            
            <video
                src="./assets/video/hero.mp4"
                class="welcome-section__video"
                playsinline
                autoplay
                muted
                preload="auto"
                loop
            >
                <source type="video/mp4" src="./assets/video/hero.mp4"/>
                <source type="video/webm" src="./assets/video/hero.webm" />
            </video>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.welcome-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.welcome-section__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```